# Restrict AWS users to only allow them to launch EC2 instance into a specific subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have users that I want to restrict which subnets they can launch EC2 in but can't seem to figure out how to do this. I tried digging in IAM but couldn't find it in there. Is this possible to do in AWS?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do that using the Identity and Access Management (IAM) service.
The policy below grants permission to use a specific subnet. In addition it gives open access to additional resources the user will need to properly launch an instance into a subnet: AMIs, instances, network interfaces, volumes, key pairs, etc.

When launching into a subnet, the RunInstances request requires these resources by default, so the user needs permission to access these resources when launching the instance.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:region::image/ami-*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:subnet/subnet-1a2b3c4d",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:network-interface/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:volume/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:key-pair/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:security-group/sg-123abc123"
      ]
    }
   ]
}
```

Note the policy also provides access to a specific security group.  You could make these fixed as needed, or provide * scope to allow them to specify any security group.

For more information, see [Launching instances into a specific subnet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_IAM.html#subnet-sg-example-iam)

Comment: Please take a moment to summarize the link's content in your answer body, [link-only answers are very brittle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and if anything ever happens to that link, then your answer's body would unfortunately offer very little insight into resolving this question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Rodrigo's answer, I had to add a number of permissions to the global resource to allow users to launch and manage instances through the web console:

```
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeImages",
            "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeVpc*",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:DescribeSpotPriceHistory",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
```

You may need to add a few more, depending on what exactly you want to allow your restricted users to do.

You can find the list of actions [on Amazon's website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html), but when lacking permissions, you have to do some digging in the browser's error console - they just show up as unhandled 403s, for the most part.

Amazon is very slowly adding [resource-level permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html), which will allow you to restrict things like "only show instances that are in this subnet", but until they do that, you can either let them see all instances or none of them.